# Center content in Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

[image: Example 1]

I want the content of a grid to be centered. Like the example above.
The **Boxes** are dynamic. Like the example there can be multiple **Box** on a row and multiple rows. The **Nav** is always there.

I want the Boxes and Nav to be centered.

[image: Example 2]

My problem is in the above image. When the screen becomes smaller the **Boxes** should line break like the example however the distance between **Boxes** and **Nav** is of. This is becuase I can't set width:fit-content on the left column since the boxes are dynamic.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-voice-u1pkie?file=/src/styles.css)

## Update

[image]
This is what the end result should look like.

The sidebar is always there to the right but the number of boxes to the left can vary per row. The amount of rows with boxes can also vary.

Comment: i dont understand what do you want

Comment: I don't want the spacing between the boxes and nav in the second image.
It should just be whatever I set gridgap too

Comment: when they wrap boxes can grow to fill the empty place or they can shrink and then wrap i think there is no other options

Answer (score 1):

Understand you, here is what you need.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img,
picture {
  max-width: 100%;
  display:block;
}


body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: bisque;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr 1fr ;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap:2rem;
}

.first-row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.second-row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
  min-width: 5rem;
  width:100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 5rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav{
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="boxes">
        <div class="first-row">
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-row">
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav"></div>
</div>
```

**Also check this please**

[flex-box: shrink before wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125962/flex-box-shrink-before-wrap)

Comment: Not really, sorry for not being able to clearly explain what I want.
The greenyellow boxes should always be the same width.
The div with the class='boxes' somethimes on linebreak is wider than the space the greenyellow boxes. The width should be 'fit-content' or something

Comment: I still dont understand can you explain it with a paint image or something else @Benny